# How to display 12months with material-ui

Tags: typescript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new with ReactJs, TypeScript and material-ui, and I need to display something like this.

[image: 12 months]

Is it possible with material-ui? If no, what may help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using material-ui. You can try https://github.com/BelkaLab/react-yearly-calendar